# CMakeLists Issue: bad_alloc error when calling resize() on thrust::device_vector

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake, thrust

I am new to thrust library and trying to use it in my project. Here is a very simple code example. It can be compiled without any problem. However, when I try to run it, it gives me an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::detail::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc: unknown error
```

along with a warning:

```
nvlink warning : SM Arch ('sm_20') not found in ...
```

The project can be reproduced by using the following two files.

test.cpp

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
int main(){
    thrust::device_vector<int> x;
    x.resize(10);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(test_project)
find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)                                                                                                     
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++11;-arch=compute_52")
set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
cuda_add_executable("cuda_test" "test.cu")
```

After some testing, it is obvious that if the line "set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)" is removed, the program runs without problem. But I really need separable compilation activated for my project.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Requested by @RobertCrovella, here are some more infos.

The CUDA version is 7.5, which is newly installed on UBUNTU 14.04 with GTX980. I did not update the Thrust library after that.

The following is the actual command generated by cmake by using "make VERBOSE=1".

[CMake script with separable compilation](http://pastebin.com/R5bAikVm)

[CMake script without separable compilation](http://pastebin.com/upMaHaZ1)

**UPDATE 2:**

The same error is confirmed by [@merelyMark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489395/6018272). Since both the code and the CMakeLists file are extremely simple, is it possible that this is a bug in Thrust / CUDA ? [EDIT] No.

**UPDATE 3:**

Pointed out by @RobertCrovella, thrust library is working fine with proper [cmake comands](http://pastebin.com/NpNArGC7). Now the question: how can I generate those commands using CMakeLists?

Comment: what are the actual compile commands being generated by cmake?  Which CUDA version are you using?  Have you updated the thrust version at all?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for asking. I have updated the info you requested on the main post.

Comment: The commands you've shown aren't generating relocatable device code in CUDA.  Are you sure this is using a CMake script with `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON` ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry, my bad. What I posted was the CMake script without separable compilation on. It is fixed now.

Comment: There is no problem with CUDA or thrust.  The problem lies within CMake, or else with your CMakeLists.txt file.  I can compile and run your code successfully with a sequence of proper compile commands, even with separable compilation.  A fully worked example is [here](http://pastebin.com/NpNArGC7), showing the critical compilation commands that CMake is generating along with the warning and runtime error, followed by the correct compilation commands, which produce no compilation warning, and no runtime error.

Comment: If you want help with CMake, you might want to tag your question with `CMake`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519394/thrust-error-with-cuda-separate-compilation) is a working example of thrust with separable compilation turned on (not using CMake).